# Don't simplify an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression that I want Mathematica to fully expand without any simplification afterwards. I want the output to look like the following example.

> ```
> (x+y)^2 ⇒ x^2+xy+yx+y^2
> ```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Something like `Distribute[(x + y) ** (x + y)] /. t_ ** t_ :> t^2`?

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mathematica.SE, Parisa! Please consider [registering your account](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/login). You will then be able to accumulate your reputation points no matter where you post from, and thus [be able to do more on the site over time](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges), such as vote up and participate in chat.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
Expand[(x + y)^2]
```

which will give you

> $ x^2 + 2 x y + y^2$

Even `ExpandAll[]` won't separate the $"2 xy"$ into $"xy+yx"$. And this makes sense; what should it make of $"3xy"$? $"xy + yx + xy"$, or $"xy + yx +yx"$? And what about $"10 xy"$ (I don't want to think about  $"10000 xy"$)?

*J.M.*'s solution

```
Distribute[(x + y) ** (x + y)] /. t_ ** t_ :> t^2
```

will give you the $2 x y$ as separate terms, but has to use the symbol for non-commutative multiplication (for example, x and y may be operators):

> $ x^2 + y^2 + x ** y + y** x $

and Mathematica won't interpret it as commutative multiplication. Replacing x and y with numerical values

```
x^2 + y^2 + x ** y + y ** x /. {x -> 2, y -> 3}
```

will yield

> $13 + 2 ** 3 + 3 ** 2$

instead of

> $ 25$

Answer (score 3):

```
Defer@*Plus @@ (If[SameQ[##], Times, CenterDot][##] & @@@ Tuples[{x, y}, 2])
% /. {x -> 3, y -> 4}
```

[image]