# How to tell Mathematica not to simplify an expression

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions, version-6

While there is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11651/7508) question with a very similar title, it does not answer my question, which is:

I have part of an input, in my case

```
Re[Exp[I*x]]
```

which *Mathematica* "simplifies" to

> ```
> Cos[Re[x]]/E^Im[x]
> ```

So I am wondering how to tell *Mathematica* to leave this expression, whether it's alone or part of a longer formula, in its previous form rather than to change it as shown here.

#### Update

I should probably add I am still running version 6, hoping this is not causing the issue.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. `Re[Exp[I*x]]` does not automatically simplify to anything. Evaluating it leaves it unchanged. Evaluating `Re[Exp[I*x]] // Simplify` doesn't change it either.

Comment: Maybe this is because I am still running Mathematica v6? But should it behave differently in such a way? If I evaluate `Re[Exp[I*x]]` in a new notebook, I get the above expression.

Comment: i agree with @m_goldberg, but if you want to suppress on the fly simplification from Mathematica enclose it in a HoldForm expression. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @Stefan, `HoldForm` might work but it seems be a little tricky to use in this case if I want to use the expression in a longer formula e.g. involving slots (`#`) where the evaluation must not be stopped. I was hoping there would be some solution of the form `expression //SomeForm`?

Comment: @Bernd what about Defer@Integrate[x^# Exp[-x], {x, 0, 1}]&/@Range[2] ?

Comment: @Stefan It seems like `Defer` does the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Stefan Me too :) I'm just randomly scanning unanswered questions from time to time :)

Comment: @Kuba that is absolutely valuable. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want Mathematica to suppress on the fly simplification and having slots (`#`) involved, you might consider using `Defer`:

```
Defer@Integrate[x^# Exp[-x], {x, 0, 1}]&/@Range[2]
```

> [image]