# How to tell Mathematica to avoid simplification of product of exponentials with the same base?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

There has been a similar [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28604/how-to-tell-mathematica-not-to-simplify-an-expression), but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have this input:

```
var = Exp[a] Exp[b]
```

And the output is

```
E^(a + b)
```

What I actually would like to have is just

```
var = E^(a)E^(b)
```

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to stop doing this simplification?

I tried with HoldForm, or Defer, but I actually need to operate on the variable, and those functions do not allow that. My idea would be to use SetSystemOptions, but I haven't found an option that relates to this simplification.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try using `var = Inactivate[Exp[a] Exp[b], Exp]`, and see if that does what you want. `Inactivate` allows you to do symbolic manipulation with everything except for `Exp`. You can always re-activate `Exp` at the end by applying `Activate` to your expression.

Comment: @march @Andrea I've tried this and I can't get it to delay the re-simplification of Exp[a]Exp[b]. For example: `expr = Exp[a (b + c) + d (f + g)`, then to get a list of the individual Exp terms: `ts = Flatten[(# //. {Exp[Plus[a_, b_]] :> { Exp[a], Exp[b]}, 
       Power[E, Plus[a_, b_, c___]] :> {Exp[First[a]], 
         Exp[ Rest[a]]}}) & /@ {ExpandAll[expr]}]`, and then inactivate the Exp and Apply Times over the list: `garb = Times @@ (ts /. Exp[a_] :> Inactive[Exp][a])`, but notice that: `Activate[garb]` doesn't prevent the product of exponentials becoming and exponential of a sum.

Comment: Would it be an option to replace `Exp` with `exp`? This will not be simplified, of course. You can do your calculations and replace agaun afterwards

Comment: @CraigCarter. See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90056/29734). Andrea: also see that answer. In addition, you can `Inactivate` `Power`, which might be necessary since your title seems to indicate that you want to do this with exponentials of arbitrary bases.

Comment: Thanks everybody. It seems like Inactivate does the job. Together with Craig's solution I should be able to first expand the exponentials, and then operate on them through Activate.

Answer (score 2):

Here I can give a not so intelligent method, for you should judge how many terms in the exponential term. Use the Rule to change back to the require form the code is

```
Exp[x b + y + z] /. {Exp[a_ + b_ + c_] :> Defer[Exp[a] Exp[b] Exp[c]]}
```

then get the result

```
(*Exp[b x] Exp[y] Exp[z]*)
```

I don't know how to made this Rule more intelligent. But sometimes it can works

Or use this command

```
Exp[x b + y + z] /. Exp[S : Plus[___]] :> HoldForm[Times] @@ Evaluate[Exp[List @@ S]]
```

But The result is

```
(*Times[E^(b x), E^y, E^z]*)
```

Thanks to previous answer. As a upgrade, you can use the methon in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90055/separating-exponential-terms/90056#90056), Firstly, set a Listable Attribute to the new symobl, Then give a HoldForm style Exp to this function, then use the rule in privious

```
SetAttributes[ExpT, Listable];
ExpT[x_] := HoldForm[Exp[x]]
Exp[x b + y + z] /. Exp[S : Plus[___]] :> Times @@ ExpT[List @@ S]
```

Then the result will be

```
(*Exp[b x] Exp[y] Exp[z]*)
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90056/29734).

Comment: I have upgrade my answer, please have a check.  @march